# Powershell JAR executable occupies instance

Tags: powershell, execution, nonblocking

I try to write a powershell script to run my Jar, which is just a simple hello world spring web mvc app using tomcat catalina servlet. The problem is that after I execute my Jar file, the powershell instance is occupied by the servlet. Which means I cant run a consecutive command -> open chrome on localhost:8080.

My current powershell script:

```
java -jar .\helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

# doesnt get executed due to the servlet occupation of the ps instance
Start-Process "chrome.exe" "http://localhost:8080"
```

Is there a way to run the second comand within the same powershell instance, or would I need to open another ps insance? And if, how would I do that?

Comment: Does it allow the second line to execute if you capture the first one in a variable i.e. `$hello =  & java -jar .\helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. I added the [Call Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#call-operator-), this is often useful when running other command line utilities in PowerShell.

Comment: @Ash I think the intent here is to make the first command _asynchronous_, on which neither assigning to a variable nor the use of `&` have any impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing Java code with `java.exe` runs the code *synchronously*, i.e. in a *blocking* fashion. Therefore, the `Start-Process` call isn't reached until after the server has shut down, which is obviously not the intent.

You have two basic choices for making the call *asynchronous*:

- Use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) to run the command in a *new window* (Windows only):

```
# Opens the server in a *new window* (Windows only)
Start-Process java '-jar .\helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
```

- Use a background or thread job ([`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Start-Job) or [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) [v6+]), which runs the command in an invisible background process or thread that you can monitor and manage with the `*-Job` cmdlets:

```
# Start the server in a background process.
# In PowerShell [Core] 6+ you can use the lighter-weight Start-ThreadJob cmdlet.
# Monitor it with the *-Job cmdlets, such as Receive-Job.
$jb = Start-Job { java -jar .\helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar }

# Syntactically simpler PowerShell [Core] v6+ alternative:
# (A postpositional & is the same as using Start-Job.
# As of PowerShell 7.0, there is no operator for Start-ThreadJob.)
$jb = java -jar .\helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &
```

Use `Receive-Job $jb` to get the job's output and `Stop-Job $jb` to stop it (and thereby the server).